# How to get the form data when the form is in a directive in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this this template:

```
<div class="modal" id="popupModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createBuildingLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="createBuildingLabel">{{ title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <form data-ng-submit="submit()">
                <div class="modal-body" data-ng-transclude>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="visible = false">Annuleren</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Maken</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's the directive:

```
app.directive("modalPopup", [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'Utils/ModalPopup',
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            onSubmit: '&',
            visible: '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            var container = $("#popupModal");

            scope.submit = function (newGroup) {
                scope.onSubmit(newGroup);
            }

            scope.hide = function () {
                container.modal('hide');
            }

            scope.show = function () {
                container.modal('show');
            }

            scope.$watch('visible', function (newVal, oldVal) {

                if (newVal === true) {
                    scope.show();
                }
                else {
                    scope.hide();
                }
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

As you can see I have declared my `form` tag inside the directive and I also use `transclude` to determine how my form is going to look like. For now I have this:

```
<modal-popup title="Nieuwe groep aanmaken" data-on-submit="createGroup()" visible="showAddGroupForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">Kopieren van:</div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="newGroup.Year">
                <option value="">Nieuw jaar</option>
                <option data-ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year.Id}}">{{year.Name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">Naam</div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="newGroup.Name" />
        </div>
    </div>
</modal-popup>
```

When the submit button is pressed, I want the data to be available in my controller.

I ques the data isn't available because of the isolated scope, however I'm not sure. What do I need to do to get the data back from the directive into my controller?

PS: I know about angular-ui and angularstrap, but I'm doing this to learn about Angular.

EDIT:

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martijngr/zL8Sj/1/)

Comment: suggest you create a demo in plunker

Comment: It seems that `newGroup` and `createGroup()` are defined in an unseen controller. Submitting the form (from the directive) should call this `createGroup()` *and the argument will be undefined*. Can you insert a breakpoint in <directive link fn>.`submit()` to verify this?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I've added a fiddle

Comment: @charlietfl I've added a fiddle

Comment: I posted an answer, the "daemon" submitted it half-done, so I deleted it, completed and undeleted it. Please see it below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the cause is a misunderstanding about how scopes work (especially with transclusion).

Let's start with this code (from the fiddle):

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <my-popup on-submit="formSubmitted(model)">
        <input type="text" ng-model="model.Name"/>    
    </my-popup>
</div>
```

Since `<my-popup>` *transcludes* its content, the scope above is that of `MyCtrl`, even in the content of the directive. By content I mean the `<input>`, *NOT* the directive template, i.e. the `<div><form ...` code.

Therefore it is implied that `model` (as used in `ng-model="model.Name"`) is a property of the scope of `MyCtrl`, as is `formSubmitted()`. Since both are members of the same scope, you do not need to pass the model as argument; you could just do:

(in the template:)

```
<my-popup on-submit="formSubmitted()"><!-- no `model` argument -->
```

(the controller:)

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    // I like declaring $scope members explicitly,
    // though it can work without it (charlietfl comments)
    $scope.model = {}; 
    $scope.submittedValue = null;
    $scope.formSubmitted = function() {
        // another bug was here; `model` is always a member of the `$scope`
        // object, not a local var
        $scope.submittedValue = $scope.model.Name;
    }
}
```

Another bug is in the directive code:

```
link: function(scope, element, attributes){
    scope.submit = function(){
        scope.onSubmit({model: model});
    }
}
```

The variable `model` (not the name `model:`) is undefined! It is a property of the *parent* scope, so you would have a chance if the scope was not isolated. With the isolated scope of the directive, it may work with an awful workaround that I am not even considering to write :)

Luckily, you do not need the directive to know about things happening in the external scope. The directive has one function, to display the form and the submit button and invoke a callback when the submit button is clicked. So the following is not only enough for this example, but also conceptually correct (the directive does not care what is happenning outside it):

```
link: function(scope, element, attributes){
    scope.submit = function(){
        scope.onSubmit();
    }
}
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PRnYg/

---

By the way: You are using Angular v1.0.1. This is *WAAAAY* too old, seriously consider upgrading!!! If you *do* upgrade, add the closing `</div>` to the template: `<div ng-transclude></div>`.

Comment: Thanx for the explanation and the solution! Didn't know the part about scopes and transclusion.

Comment: disagree about must declare model variables related to `ng-model`. That is one of the cool things about `ng-model`. If the scope variable is undefined when angular first digests the form, angular creates it and the 2 way binding is automatic from then on..even if it's an object. One other thing, model may be bound to controller, but isolated scope of directive causes issues with the form validation scope so directive does need to know about parent scope...see [Isolated Scope Pitfall/ ngController docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController)

Comment: example empty controller , with fully working `ng-model`  , http://jsfiddle.net/Mhr8C/

Comment: @charlietfl good point about undefined stuff. I still like to be explicit in their declarations though.

Comment: Understood...I do too, but in big form is very convenient to let angular do it's thing. dealing with validation of inputs within directives with isolated scopes...that's another story