# ng-model returning 'undefined' from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement a system of reddit-like nested comments with reply fields hidden with `ng-show`.

However when I attempt to return the comment from a custom directive into the controller, the result is always 'undefined'.

I've followed this tutorial:

> [How to get the form data when the form is in a directive in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097757/how-to-get-the-form-data-when-the-form-is-in-a-directive-in-angular)

but it's not working for me.

```
app.directive("replyContainer", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            onSubmit: "&"
        },
        template: '<a ng-click="replyForm = !replyForm">reply</a>' +
          '<div ng-show="replyForm" id="replyForm">' +
            '<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-transclude'+
            'ng-show="isLoggedIn()"'+
            'style="margin-top:30px;">'+
              '<h3>Reply</h3>'+
              '<div class="form-group">'+
                '<input type="text" '+
                'class="form-control"'+
                'placeholder="Comment"'+
                'parent="{{comment._id}}"'+
                '<script>console.log(parent)</script>'
                'ng-model="model.Name"></input>'+
              '</div>'+
              '<button ng-click="submit()"'+
              'class="btn btn-primary">Reply</button>'+
            '</form>'+
            '</div>',
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.submit = function() {
                scope.onSubmit();
            }
        }

    }
})
app.controller('PostsCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts', 'post', 'auth',
function($scope, posts, post, auth) {

    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.submittedValue = null;
    $scope.post = post;
    $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;
    $scope.replyForm = false;

    $scope.addReply = function (){
        $scope.submittedValue = $scope.model.Name;
        console.log($scope.parent);
    };
```

index.ejs:

```
<reply-container on-submit="addReply()"></reply-container>
```

Comment: you probably need to wrap your submit function inside  $scope.$apply().

Comment: I've read a bit about $scope.apply() and tried it in various places in my code but I'm not sure how to implement this